# this.stage.loaderInfo.bytesLoaded returns 0

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs3

Here is the code : You can see it live at : http://humordestination.com/game/

```
stop();
this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loadingPL);
function loadingPL(e:Event):void{
    var totalData:Number = this.stage.loaderInfo.bytesTotal;
    var loadedData:Number = this.stage.loaderInfo.bytesLoaded;
    loaderGreen.width = loadedData/totalData * progressText.width;
    progressText.text=String(Math.floor(loadedData/totalData*100)) + "%";
    TotalData.text=totalData.toString();
    LoadedYet.text=loadedData.toString();
    if (loadedData == totalData) {
            gotoAndStop(2);
            this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loadingPL);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you ask stage instead of `this`?

Comment: Okay I changed it to this now, but still the same issue:
stop();
this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loadingPL);
function loadingPL(e:Event):void{
 var totalData:Number =  this.loaderInfo.bytesTotal;
    var loadedData:Number = this.loaderInfo.bytesLoaded;
    loaderGreen.width = loadedData/totalData * progressText.width;
 progressText.text=String(Math.floor(loadedData/totalData*100))+"%";
TotalData.text=totalData.toString();
LoadedYet.text=loadedData.toString();
   if (loadedData == totalData) {
   gotoAndStop(2);
            this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loadingPL);
    }}

Comment: Please update your question instead of writing several lines of code in the commentary. Thanks

Comment: @Kodiak the problem is this.stage.loaderInfo.bytesLoaded returns 0